# Two different methods of obtaining max row

Tags: sql, sql-server, min, window-functions

The first statement is how I have needed to pull a min row based on the org's needs I work for. At first, I would `MIN(DATEFIELD)` but if someone has two entries on the same day, we had problems. Next I tried `MIN(OP__DOCID)` where OP__DOCID is the table's unique key. Problem here is if someone ever back-dated an entry they forgot to create, the results would be inaccurate. So, I came up with the below statement. It ensures I get the most recent result from each unique admission.

```
SELECT OP__DocID
FROM FD__CNSLG_BASIS24 AS PC1
WHERE (OP__DOCID = 
        (SELECT TOP(1)OP__DocID
            FROM FD__CNSLG_BASIS24 AS PC2
            WHERE PC2.ClientKey = PC1.Clientkey and PC2.ProgramAdmitKey = PC1.Programadmitkey
            ORDER BY Date_Screening
        )
    )
```

Recently, I have learned about `OVER(PARTITION BY)` and have been curious as to the subtle differences in how it works v.s. the statement above, because I do get different result.

```
SELECT OP__DocID = Min(OP__DOCID) OVER (Partition BY Clientkey, Programadmitkey)
FROM FD__CNSLG_BASIS24
```

Any insight, or links to other pages I could read would be extremely helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the structure of the data,  some sample data,  and what are the differences you're finding between the two queries? Also,  it would be useful if you could tell as what's the desired outcome.

Comment: Also,  you could tag the question with the rdbms you're using (sqlserver,  mysql,...)

Comment: Sorry about the missing info. What Gordon posted below hit what I was looking for. The desired outcome was to retrieve the 1st record. I am also trying to retrieve the most recent record as well (which is why I typoed with MAX instead of MIN above).

The differences are that certian records will appear in the first script, but not the second, and vice versa. Its only a hand full, so I am thinking it may be something unique to that record... which means having to look at each of them :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use window functions:

```
select pc.*
from (select pc.*,
             row_number() over (partition by Clientkey, ProgramAdmitKey
                                order by Date_Screening  -- do you mean DESC?
                               ) as seqnum
      from FD__CNSLG_BASIS24 PC
     ) pc
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  this gets the first record based on the screening date.  You might want `DESC` to get the most recent.

Comment: OH! You can use `order by` in the OVER() function. Is row_Number the only way that `order by` works? I tried to use it with MIN(OP__DOCID) and it gave errors.

Comment: Also, I made a mistake in my original script by saying `MAX` I meant to put `MIN` in.

Comment: @J_Lyne when you say Min(op_docid) it will return the minimum value of the field op_docid,  so the order for another field is redundant and not accepted.  You might want to try use LAST_VALUE/FIRST_VALUE instead of MIN/MAX

Answer (score 0):

**My Solution, for those that were curious**

I want to go back and substitute the SELECT TOP(1) for the ROW_Number() function, but I needed to get a report out, and this is providing what I need. Thanks for everyone's help.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

Declare 
@StartDate Date,
@EndDate Date

SET @StartDate = '1/1/2016'
SET @EndDate = '6/1/2016'

WITH CNSL_Clients AS (
                SELECT PC_CNT.Clientkey, PC_Cnt.ProgramAdmitKey, PC_Cnt.OP__DOCID
                FROM FD__Primary_Client as PC_Cnt
                                INNER JOIN VW__Cnsl_Session_Count_IndvFamOnly as cnt
                                    ON PC_Cnt.Clientkey = CNT.Clientkey AND PC_Cnt.ProgramAdmitKey = CNT.ProgramAdmitKey
                WHERE ((pc_CNT.StartDate between @StartDate AND @EndDate) OR (pc_CNT.StartDate <= @StartDate AND pc_CNT.ENDDate >= @StartDate) OR (pc_CNT.StartDate <= @StartDate AND pc_CNT.ENDDate is null)) 
                AND CNT.SessionCount>=6
),

FIRST_BASIS AS (
            SELECT CB24_1.OP__DOCID, CB24_1.Date_Screening, CB24_1.ClientKey, CB24_1.ProgramAdmitKey, CB24_1.Composite_score, CB24_1.Depression_Results,CB24_1.Emotional_Results, CB24_1.Relationships_Results
            FROM FD__CNSLG_BASIS24 AS CB24_1
            WHERE (CB24_1.OP__DOCID =
                    (Select TOP(1) CB24_2.OP__DOCID
                    FROM FD__CNSLG_BASIS24 AS CB24_2
                                        Inner JOIN CNSL_Clients
                                            ON CB24_2.ClientKey = CNSL_Clients.ClientKey AND CB24_2.ProgramAdmitKey = CNSL_Clients.ProgramAdmitKey
                    WHERE (CB24_1.ClientKey = CB24_2.ClientKey) AND (CB24_1.ProgramAdmitKey = CB24_2.ProgramAdmitKey)
                    ORDER BY CB24_2.Date_Screening))
),

RECENT_BASIS AS (
            SELECT CB24_1.OP__DOCID, CB24_1.Date_Screening, CB24_1.ClientKey, CB24_1.ProgramAdmitKey, CB24_1.Composite_score, CB24_1.Depression_Results,CB24_1.Emotional_Results, CB24_1.Relationships_Results
            FROM FD__CNSLG_BASIS24 AS CB24_1
            WHERE (CB24_1.OP__DOCID =
                    (Select TOP(1) CB24_2.OP__DOCID
                    FROM FD__CNSLG_BASIS24 AS CB24_2
                                        Inner JOIN CNSL_Clients
                                            ON CB24_2.ClientKey = CNSL_Clients.ClientKey AND CB24_2.ProgramAdmitKey = CNSL_Clients.ProgramAdmitKey
                    WHERE (CB24_1.ClientKey = CB24_2.ClientKey) AND (CB24_1.ProgramAdmitKey = CB24_2.ProgramAdmitKey)
                    ORDER BY CB24_2.Date_Screening DESC))
)

SELECT F.OP__DOCID AS First_DOCID,R.OP__DOCID as Recent_DOCID,F.ClientKey, F.ProgramAdmitKey, F.Composite_Score AS FComposite_Score, R.Composite_Score as RComposite_Score, Composite_Change = R.Composite_Score - F.Composite_Score, F.Depression_Results AS FDepression_Results, R.Depression_Results AS RDepression_Resluts, Depression_Change = R.Depression_Results - F.Depression_Results, F.Emotional_Results AS FEmotional_Resluts, R.Emotional_Results AS REmotionall_Reslu, Emotional_Change = R.Emotional_Results - F.Emotional_Results, F.Relationships_Results AS FRelationships_Resluts, R.Relationships_Results AS RRelationships_Resluts, Relationship_Change = R.Relationships_Results - F.Relationships_Results
FROM First_basis AS F
        FULL Outer JOIN RECENT_BASIS AS R
            ON F.ClientKey = R.ClientKey AND F.ProgramAdmitKey = R.ProgramAdmitKey
ORDER BY F.ClientKey
END
GO
```